# Why Spring Integration Java DSL request for the JSON is not working

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the bean definition

```
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow inbound() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.queue("getSend1"))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting").httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("getReceive1"))
            .get();
}
```

and default poller and I want to get the JSON from the URL. This is not working. The service http://localhost:8055/greeting is not called at all and the log message

```
preReceive on channel 'getSend1'
postReceive on channel 'getSend1', message is null
Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
```

is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working like this:

```
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow inbound() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(this.integerMessageSource(), c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(2000)))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting")
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET).expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("getReceive"))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting").httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("postReceive"))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting-final").httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("postReceiveFinal"))
            .get();
}
```

This does get for the first URL, then posts the answer the second URL and then posts the answer to third URL and gets the final answer.